# Average values of $\langle n|x_{op}|n\rangle$ and $\langle n|p_{op}|n\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, observables

Let an harmonic oscillator described by the hamiltonian $H=p^2/2m+(1/2)mw^2x^2$.
I have determined that the average values of the observables $x$ and $p$ in energy eigenstates , $\langle n|x|n\rangle$ and $\langle n|p|n\rangle$, are equal to $0$, but I don't know if it is right or not

Comment: Note: Use \$...\$ rather than \$\$...\$\$ when you want “inline” math. And use \omega to get the Greek $\omega$.

Comment: Check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site. Do you have a *conceptual* question about this calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ only couple state $|n\rangle$ to $|n\pm 1\rangle$, so you are right: both averages vanish. This is not surprising because the left-right symmetry of the potential means that whatever happens on (or going to, for $\hat p$) the left happens on (or going to) the right half a period later.